# How to unlock my device after locking with Google's “Find My Device”?

Tags: xiaomi, locked-out, find-my-device

I now have my phone (Xiaomi Redmi 4), but it's locked from Google's "Find My Device". Everyone keeps talking about a password option in Find My Device, but nothing like that exists! How do I unlock my phone without erasing the data? Here's all I see on Google's Find My Device:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this, so for future readers:

- I went to emergency and pressed back(this brought up the phone lock screen with the pattern option). Rebooting seems to also bring up the lock screen temporarily.
- I managed to enter the lock-screen pattern correctly from muscle memory(even though it didn't seem to work all the times I had tried before). I believe if you enter it incorrectly enough times, it'll let you enter your google account info to reset the password, but I never got to that point.
- After the phone unlocked I changed my default password and all seems good now.

I'm still not sure why google wouldn't let me set a temporary password. God help anyone that doesn't remember their original one.